# Is it possible to pixelate an image without canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

Given an `<img>` element, is it possible to pixelate the image using only CSS and/or not use canvas?
I've seen things like the [crisp edges](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges) feature (but that's just for images that are scaled) and a lot of canvas options, but I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a request for a resource. It's asking about CSS techniques.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid. `image-rendering: pixelated;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: It may be possible using CSS filters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
Unfortunately there's no built-in pixelate filter but you can specify a custom filter with the url function which can pull a filter from an svg element. Inside your svg you can use a bunch of different filter effects (see the fe* elements at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element). Some combination of those filter effects might produce a pixelation effect.

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve a pixelated affect by using the `image-rendering: pixelated;` CSS rule and scaling up an image - [see this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/).

Comment: So if I want to keep the image at its natural size, what would you suggest? Scaling it, applying the `image-rendering`, and then clipping it to its original size?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: That would work although you'd be clipping off part of the image (though it is pixelated). You could also try to save the source image in a smaller size than what you actually need it to appear in on your site, apply `image-rendering: pixelate;`, and scale it up to your desired size.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, I won't have control over the images being displayed, so I can't just save it at a smaller size.

Comment: In that case, I would try to use `image-rendering` along with `transform: scale(0.5);` and something like `width: 200%; height: 200%;`. Some combination of those rules should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Worth noting that this only works in webkit-based browsers as of 2019